# How to store a function return in a variable?

Tags: string, function-pointer

I want to create a dynamic JSONpath in an Oraclize query. For that I wrote a function that concentrates three strings (_a = "json(http...",_b = some variable ,_c = ")].Number") to one. Calling the function and getting the concentrated string as a return works fine. How can I now use my concentrated string in the Oraclize query as a variable ?

```
function strConcat()public view returns (string){

bytes memory _ba = bytes(_a);
bytes memory _bb = bytes(_b);
bytes memory _bc = bytes(_c);

string memory abc = new string(_ba.length + _bb.length + _bc.length);
bytes memory babc = bytes(abc);
uint k = 0;

for (uint i = 0; i < _ba.length; i++) babc[k++] = _ba[i];
for (i = 0; i < _bb.length; i++) babc[k++] = _bb[i];
for (i = 0; i < _bc.length; i++) babc[k++] = _bc[i];
return string(babc);
}
```

Now I want to bring the function return in an Oraclize query to create a dynamic query:

```
function update() payable {
newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent...");
oraclize_query('URL', **return** );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not possible"? Can you please share a coding example?

Comment: It would be better if you clarify your question.
Do you want to make a GET request to desiredUrl i mentioned below ? 
    rootUrl = https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/
    param = comments?postId=1
    desiredUrl = https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're concatenating your string correctly, all you need to do now is call that function wherever it is you need it:

```
function update() payable {
    newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent...");
    oraclize_query('URL', strConcat());
}
```

Please note however that the string concat helper function in the Oraclize API is *also* called `strConcat`, which your function name shadows. I would write a differently named function in order to get around that issue.

---

#### Working example:

Here is a rejigged, working version of one of the Oraclize examples to show you that method in use:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

    import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

    contract DieselPrice is usingOraclize {

            uint public dieselPriceUSD;

            event LogNewDieselPrice(string price);
            event LogNewOraclizeQuery(string description);

            function __callback(bytes32 myid, string memory result) public {
                    require(msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());
                    emit LogNewDieselPrice(result);
                    dieselPriceUSD = parseInt(result, 2); // Let's save it as cents...
                    // Now do something with the USD Diesel price...
            }

            function getQueryString() public pure returns (string memory) {
                    string memory x = "xml(https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices).";
                    string memory y = "fuelPrices.diesel";
                    return strConcat(x,y);
            }

            function update() public payable {
                    emit LogNewOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer...");
                    oraclize_query("URL", getQueryString());
            }
    }
```

Paste the above code into the [Remix IDE](http://remix.ethereum.org), compile it with any compiler version greater than `0.5.0` and deploy the contract. Browse to the settings tab and fire up the Oraclize plugin, before clicking the `update` function in the run tab once your contract has deployed.

---

There are of course many ways to achieve the same thing as I have above - you could also for example set the return of your concatenating function as a variable and then use that in the `oraclize_query(...)` instead. Feel free to choose whichever method makes most sense to you!

Comment: Sometimes it can be so easy haha....thank you a lot.

Comment: Hahah yes! If only it was always so!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm understanding you wrong. If you mean to store a the return just set a variable.

```
function update() payable {

    newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent.");

    string memory x = strConcat();

    oraclize_query('URL', x);

}
```

It looks to me as long as _b has the value you want, this query would be dynamic.

Comment: doing it like that gives me the following error: "Variable is declared as storage pointer...". using the storage keyword does not help.

Comment: For this solution you'd have to declare `x` as `string memory x = //...`